# Specific sutta in the Majjhima Nikaya: Where is past and future discussed?

Tags: personal-practice, pali-canon, reference-request, tipitaka

Im looking for a specific sutta in the *Majjhima Nikaya*.

In the sutta *past and future* is being discussed and also how a practitioner on the insight path can gain seclusion from the 5 aggregates.

Help would be much appreciated.

Lanka

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on what topic about past and future was discussed in that sutta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few suttas fit this, but try this first - 
Bhaddekaratta Sutta: An Auspicious Day
http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.131.than.html

Comment: That is precisely the one! Thanks a lot.